# Roblox script error:ServerScriptService.CustomAnimee:4: attempt to index nil with 'WaitForChild'

Tags: lua, parent-child, wait, roblox

Roblox script error:ServerScriptService.CustomAnimee:4: attempt to index nil with 'WaitForChild'

I tried to change humoinid to Player but didnot work either [image] so that is the script i made it to use a custom animation for Walking i am using R6 btw but i get this error

[image]

and i cant fix it so can anyone help me ?

Comment: Heyo, please [don't post pictures of your code and error messages](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Please edit your question to include your code and errors in text form.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i am sorry its my first time here i will make sure i do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You called your `loadAnimes` callback when registering it via Connect. Not only is chars nil (since you didn't pass anything), it will also eventually crash because connect receives nil too. Don't call it.